# Updating values from select list with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I was trying to modify the [lists and collections tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) found on the knockout.js website by allowing an editable price rather than a fixed value.

Right now the lists and data populate correctly when the page loads. However, if I select a new value from the list the price and id do not change for that row. The total surcharge changes, but the row itself doesn't. Also, if I change the price manually for a given row, the total  surcharge doesn't change.

I tried setting the individual values to observables such as shown below, but the price and id values still don't update when a new list item is selected, only the total surcharge

```
function RowReservation(initialRow) {
    var self = this;

    self.row = ko.observable(initialRow);
    self.rowID = ko.observable(self.row().rowID);
    self.price = ko.observable(self.row().price);
}
```

So the two issues I can't seem to figure out

1. When a new item is selected in the list, the corresponding price and id do not change
2. If a price is manually changed, the total surcharge doesn't update

**EDIT - Number 1 of my list has been fixed, and 2 partially has.**

If I change a price in one of the text boxes for either row, the total surcharge will ONLY update if another row is added or the other row's name has been changed. Basically, it's not an immediate change, it's only computed when a new value is introduced. How can I make it so it updates automatically? Is there a way to subscribe to the price textboxes?**

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XtAt/2/)

Comment: You are setting the value at the time of instantiation, so the value is not bound to the input box and back to the list properly.  Give me a second to update your fiddle...  Actually your fiddle doesn't really make sense - your list of available rows is actually just a copy of the rows, but non-observable.  Are you sure you intended it to work this way?

Comment: @PWKad I'm new to Knockout so I'm just going to say it was a misunderstanding and I didn't intend for it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to modify in your code is this part in line 17 of your HTML

```
<input data-bind="value: price" />
```

into

```
<input data-bind="value: $data.row().price"/>
```

When you bind the 'price' initially, you were binding it to the price attribute of RowReservation object. When the 'row' value changed, the value of 'price' attribute was not updated. Therefore it still shows the original price.

I changed the binding so that it is showing the price attribute of 'row'. So when 'row' is changed by selecting different item in the combobox, the price is updated to the price of the newly selected row.

Basically you have

```
// RowReservationObject

{'row': 
    {'rowName': 'Standard',
     'rowID': 1, 
    'price': 19.99 },   // --> this is what I'm binding against now
'rowID': 1 
'price': 19.99}  // -- this is what you were binding against before
```

If you change the variable names a bit it might become clearer to you.
I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's almost working the way I wanted. I also partially fixed item #2 on my list above. If I manually change a text value the total surcharge will only update if I add another row. How can it be fixed so the total surcharge updates as any of the price textboxes are manually changed?

Comment: Actually `<input data-bind="value: row().price"/>` is all you need from this answer, don't need the $data part, but the binding still makes no sense and messes up when you do that which is why I mentioned that fundamentally something is wrong with what you are trying to do.

Comment: @PWKad as I said, I'm not quite sure what to do. This is all new to me, so I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out. I don't know what it is that I am doing wrong, or rather what the correct way to approach this problem should be.

Comment: @user3476345 The problem I see with the fiddle is that it doesn't make any sense what you are trying to do.  You have a list of items and you are trying to add new items but bind each item back to the original list.  Fundamentally it makes no sense in the context that you are using it in.

Comment: @PWKad right, and I'm asking how to approach that. I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do. I tried to make that original list an observable but that lead to other errors. Should I be binding it to a new list?

Comment: I'm sorry I spent a long time earlier trying to figure out what you are trying to do but it still makes no sense.  Why would you bind to a value of an item if you could change that items value?  Why re-calculate then?  The items are bound to the options and vice versa so it breaks the idea of binding.